# Mahout: How does one format, load and work with data for classification?

Tags: java, mahout

The JavaDocs and mahout quick start page are awful. I got a copy of the Mahout in action book.  I've read through huge swaths of the Mahout in Action book it focuses on formatting data for Reccomender systems only.

How do you format the file that holds the classification data?

How is it loaded into mahout's DataModel or is there a different data model for classification?  (I saw something about vectors)

How do you take that data model and incorporate it with your classification system?

Answer (score 0):

(Saw your other question just now.)

I don't think the docs are good in general. It only gets better when people like you add docs. But, Mahout is not a product, nor even really a library. It's code for developers and pretty much has to be used as code.

Most of the classification (of which I know little) uses `Vector` and so uses `VectorWritable` as the Hadoop wire format for input.

`DataModel` is unrelated to classifiers and there is no counterpart. That is part of the recommender bit.